# Next view id as a custom attribute in android

Tags: android, custom-attributes, custom-view

For my custom view I have also defined a custom attribute for keep id of the view. Its format is "reference".

in layout xml it is defined like below, very similar with `android:layout_below` attr

```
<mycustomview id="@+id/cv_1" xyz:nextviewId="@id/cv_2"... />
<mycustomview id="@+id/cv_2" xyz:nextviewId="@id/cv_3"... />
...
<LinearLayout ...>
    <mycustomview id="@+id/cv_3" xyz:nextviewId="@id/cv_4"... />
</LinearLayout>
...
```

it gives me error I think it is because it is not declared  yet.

Any suggestion for accessing the next object similar to this approach!!!

I am thinking to use tag attr for the next object find the next one with findByTag function. Is this a good way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your xml to:

```
...
<mycustomview id="@+id/cv_1" xyz:nextviewId="@+id/cv_2"... />
<mycustomview id="@+id/cv_2" xyz:nextviewId="@+id/cv_3"... />
...
```

(note the `@+id` in `nextviewId`)

This will work on Android 1.6+ (Api Level 4+). Exactly the same approach is used in `RelativeLayout`s.

Comment: Learned something today. So, in a relative layout, you can use that approach to refer to a view that is defined below the current one? That's awesome!

Comment: I tried but for some reason it is not working in my layout. API Level 7 and code structure is ;

<linerlayout..
    <mycustomview id="@+id/cv_1" xyz:nextviewId="@+id/cv_2".../>
    <linerlayout..>
       <linerlayout..>
               <mycustomview id="@+id/cv_2" xyz:nextviewId="@+id/cv_3".../>
       </linerlayout>
       </linerlayout>
</linerlayout>

It does not give any error but the nextviewId returns 0.

Comment: thank for your comment I was using ´TypedArray.getInt()´. After your comment I checked the alternatives and apparently I had use ´TypedArray.getResourceId´.