# How to pass view reference to android custom view?

Tags: android, custom-view

I did as follows

1) Creating a styleable

```
<declare-styleable name="Viewee">
    <attr name="linkedView" format="reference"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

2) defining custom view layout

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffc0">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custom_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="[text]"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

3) Creating required class

```
public class Viewee extends LinearLayout
{
public Viewee(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet)
{
    super(context, attributeSet);
    View.inflate(context, R.layout.viewee, this);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_text);
    TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.Viewee);
    int id = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.Viewee_linkedView, 0);
    if (id != 0)
    {
        View view = findViewById(id);
        textView.setText(((TextView) view).getText().toString());
    }

    typedArray.recycle();
}
}
```

and finally in an activity like below

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.ns"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTest"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="android"/>
    <com.ns.Viewee
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            app:linkedView="@+id/tvTest"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

now although I recieve a non zero `id` in Viewee constractor, `findViewById(id)` retuns null and `NullPointerException` occures.

what am I missing?

[I did it as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426930/next-view-id-as-a-custom-attribute-in-android)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found the answer!

The issue was with `findViewById(id)` and where I called it. `findViewById` only looks for a child view not a view exist on upper hierarchy level as [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) says . So I have to call something like `getRootView().findViewById(id)` but that also returns `null` becase where I called it was not corrent.

In `Viewee` constractor `Viewee` itself has not attached to its root yet so that call causes `NullPointerException`.

So If I call to `getRootView().findViewById(id)` somewhere else after constraction, it works fine and both `"@+id/tvTest"` and `"@id/tvTest"` are correct. I've tested it!

the answer is as follows

```
public class Viewee extends LinearLayout
{
    public Viewee(Context context, AttributeSet a)
    {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.main6, this);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_text);
        TypedArray t = context.obtainStyledAttributes(a, R.styleable.Viewee);
        int id = t.getResourceId(R.styleable.Viewee_linkedView, 0);
        if (id != 0)
        {
            _id = id;
        }

        t.recycle();
    }

    private int _id;

    public void Foo()
    {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_text);
        View view = getRootView().findViewById(_id);
        textView.setText(((TextView) view).getText().toString());
    }
}
```

and `Foo` is called when it is required to process the attached view via its reference id somewhere else in your activity and the like.

The credit completely goes to those guys contributed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624973/android-custom-view-with-object-reference-from-attrs-xml-always-null). I had not seen that post before submitting the question.

Comment: do NOT place it in `onDraw` but in `onAttachedToWindow`. Placing it in onDraw will called X times per second the method, could be 60 times per seconds. @DanielWilson can you remove your comment?

Answer (score 19):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I would add another way of doing this as I wanted to encapsulate everything into my custom view.

Instead of calling from the outside, another way of getting a view higher up in the hierarchy, I've hooked into `onAttachedToWindow()` instead:

```
public class MyCustomView extends LinearLayout {
    private int siblingResourceId;
    private View siblingView;

    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet a) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        inflate(context, R.layout.main6, this);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_text);
        TypedArray t = context.obtainStyledAttributes(a, R.styleable.Viewee);
        siblingResourceId = t.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyCustomView_siblingResourceId, NO_ID);
        t.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        if (siblingResourceId != NO_ID) {
            siblingView = ((View) getParent()).findViewById(siblingResourceId);
        }
    }
}
```

`onAttachedToWindow` is called quite early, but apparently late enough for the whole view hierarchy to have settled. It works flawless for my needs at least and is a little bit more controlled and doesn't need interaction from outside to work ;-)

**EDIT:** Kotlin code added

```
class MyCustomView(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : LinearLayout(context, attributeSet) {
    private val siblingResourceId: Int
    private lateinit var siblingView: View

    // All other constructors left out for brevity.

    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.main6, this)
        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.custom_text)
        val t = context.obtainStyledAttributes(a, R.styleable.Viewee)
        siblingResourceId = t.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyCustomView_siblingResourceId, NO_ID)
        t.recycle()
    }

    override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow()
        if (siblingResourceId != NO_ID) {
            siblingView = (parent as View).findViewById(siblingResourceId) 
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** We assume that the `parent` of this custom `View` is a `View` itself.

Comment: If there was other view with same id in upper level this will get that view

Comment: @Alimohammadi not sure if that makes sense - how can you build a layout with 2 of the same ids? It shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Think about fragment in activity .consider we have same id in activity.xml and fragment.xml file and  this return view that is in activity

Comment: @Alimohammadi it's not relevant as we're inside a custom view, not a `Fragment` or an `Activity` for that matter. 
This is what the docs says about `findViewById` inside a `View` class: 
Finds the first descendant view with the given ID, the view itself if the ID matches {@link #getId()}, or {@code null} if the ID is invalid (< 0) or there is no matching view in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

Your described `android:id` is set to `app:linkedView="@+id/tvTest`. However, `@+id/tvTest` is used to create a new id with name "tvTest". What you want  to do is use `app:linkedView="@id/tvTest`.

Comment: I applied your answer though `View view = findViewById(id);` still returns null!

Comment: Why are you using `id` to hold the id of the View? It should be fairly straightforward to use `R.id.foo` instead of creating another variable. Also, I can't tell through your comment whether you changed the `app:linkedView` attribute of your `<com.ns.Viewee />` element to `"@id/tvTest`.

Comment: I have to hold the `id` because `Viewee` is a custom view refering to another view for a reson. I can not refer to the linked view as `R.id.foo` as you said. what if I use `Viewee` in another layout where `R.id.foo` not exist? I also did as you recommended and changed `"@+id/tvTest"` to `"@id/tvTest"` but with no success.

Comment: @+id instead of @id is not relevant, plus sign is fine